# I have used CKEditor through cdn but I can not send data to the database

Tags: php

I want to send data to my database but I do not get any data written to the database. Below I have the code. Is there a mistake in my code or is my code incomplete?

```html
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','rich_text_editor'); 
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>myEditor</title>
         <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
         </head>
         <body>
         <form method="POST" action="index.php">
         <textarea name="myeditor" id="myeditor" rows="70" cols="70">
         MudasirAbbasTuri! We are building a simple editor.
         </textarea>

         <input type="submit" name="submit">
         </form>
         <script>
         CKEDITOR.replace('myeditor');
         </script>
         </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $content = $_POST["myeditor"];
        $qry ="INSERT INTO `mycontent`(`editor_content`) VALUES ('$content')";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting, if any?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, I've fixed some potential problems:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','rich_text_editor'); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["myeditor"]);
        $qry ="INSERT INTO mycontent (editor_content) VALUES ('$content')";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>myEditor</title>
     <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form method="POST" action="">
         <textarea name="myeditor" id="myeditor" rows="70" cols="70">
             MudasirAbbasTuri! We are building a simple editor.
         </textarea>
         <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>
     <script>
         CKEDITOR.replace('myeditor');
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Also note that if you're posting form data to the same file, you can just leave the `action` attribute blank in the `<form>` tag (`<form method="POST" action="">`)

Comment: @mudasirabbas If my answer solved your problem, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: hi dear, where to mark please say me i do not know where is the mark sign

Comment: There is a tick close to the top of my answer and when you click it, it should turn green.